# Firebird SQL Query with @ (at) sign - How to run the query in JDBC (Jaybird)?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I have an application that uses Firebird. The application performs a long list of queries e.g. each time you list your items. I want to take out these queries, and run them in my own Java application (so I can manipulate the list, display it, and so on.)

The problem is... there is a debug option in the application where you can see what kind of queries does your application run. Some of the original queries got `@` signs. If I run a query with an `@` in it, I get an error. If I take out that part of the query, everything runs and works "as expected". No errors, like a charm.

Detailed error message:
Error code: -104
Token unknown - line 8, column 32

We use IntelliJ IDEA which automatically applies escape characters when needed.
Such a part from the original query:

```
SELECT  TBL4487."Id" "database.id",
       TBL4487."Code" "database.code",
       TBL4487."Name" "database.name",
       TBL4487."Barcode" "database.barcode",
       TBL4488."Name" "Datagroup",
       TBL4489."Name" "Mey",
       (SELECT FIRST 1   TBL4494."Price" / (CASE
    WHEN (TBL4487."GrossPrices" = @Param4495) THEN 1
    ELSE (TBL4492."Rate" + 100) / 100
END) "productprice.price"
FROM "ProductPrice" TBL4494
WHERE (TBL4494."Product" = TBL4487."Id") AND (TBL4494."PriceCategory" = @Param4497) AND (TBL4494."ValidFrom" <= @Param4498) AND (TBL4494."Currency" = @Param4499) AND (TBL4494."QuantityUnit" = TBL4487."QuantityUnit")
ORDER BY TBL4494."ValidFrom" DESC) "xyz",
       (SELECT FIRST 1   TBL4500."Price" / (CASE
    WHEN (TBL4487."GrossPrices" = @Param4501) THEN 1
    ELSE (TBL4492."Rate" + 100) / 100
```

The question is.. how could I run this query? How do I replace the `@` symbol?

Comment: If anyone curious, you can log the queries with Firebird Scanner. It's proprietary and stuff, but at least you can see the exact queries, that you can implement in code later. (Not that flexible, but if you need a handful of queries max, it works perfect.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run this query directly with Jaybird. These `@ParamXXXX` seem to be placeholders in the query for parameters. However Firebird nor Jaybird supports this type of placeholders (they only support `?` as placeholder in DSQL).

To execute this with Jaybird, you will need to replace each instance of the `@ParamXXXX` either with a `?` and set the right value for each placeholder in a `PreparedStatement`, or with the actual value in the query text itself.

The Firebird .NET provider does support `@....`-style placeholders (it translates them to Firebird-style `?` placeholders), so you could try to use C#/.NET instead if you don't want to do replacing yourself.

*Full disclosure: I am the developer of Jaybird*

Comment: is there any planned feature to accept parameter placeholders in `Jaybird`, such as for example the .NET one you mention or the `:param`-style that you can use from `Zeos` or `Delphi` components?

Comment: @GuillemVicens No there are no plans to support this: JDBC does not provide an API for named parameters in queries which would force users to use a Jaybird specific interface which IMHO is bad, also Firebird itself does not support named parameters, which means added complexity in the driver to parse parameters and map them to positional placeholders, and finally my time to work on Jaybird is finite and IMO there are more important things to improve/add to Jaybird.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Both solutions are pretty OK with me, but I just can't figure out the parameters. Where could I find these? I looked at all the queries in the application but there are no parameters anywhere. I also looked at the "FBscan" application, but it didn't work (the application is written in C# that I have to work with, and it works with Firebird 2.1) || I know this "bonus" is not part of the question, kudos for the solution. Hope you can help me though. :)

Comment: @Shiki If the application does not log the actual parameter values, then you would need to find them yourself (not sure of good tools for that though)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Thank you for the fast reply. We will work this out somehow. Ps.: Keep up the great work!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, fair enough. It was just a bit of curiosity on my side :-)